# Savage Worlds wild dice and attacking with two weapons

Tags: savage-worlds

If you use 2 swords in Savage Worlds, do you get a wild die for each attack in one round, or do you just get one for the main hand attack and none for the offhand? I know it would be the same *kind* of action (attacking) but it is with two different hands/weapons.

Answer (score 13):

You get one Wild Die per action. Each separate weapon attack counts as a unique actions. Hence you roll a Wild Die for each hand but you still get the Multi-Action penalty. See **Two Weapons** in the **Savage World Deluxe** rule book.

Comment: You can lower the penalty by taking the Edge for two-weapon fighting.

Comment: @NeoFax - yep that is true.

Answer (score -3):

You can only roll each skill once per turn, so you treat attacking with each hand as if you had a "rate of fire" of two. Roll two Skill Dice and one Wild Die. Take the two highest, and factor in any mishaps should a 1 come up on one of the Skill Dice. Don't forget to factor in the off-hand penalty if the character isn't Ambidextrous.

If someone decides to spend a Benny because of poor roles, it's 1 Benny per Skill Die.

Comment: Can you give a page cite? I'm looking at SWDE p. 66 and it's pretty clear that the restriction is that you can't roll Fighting twice with the *same* weapon—the example even describes making two Fighting actions with two weapons—but I could be missing a rule elsewhere.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  See http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36639&highlight=two+fisted for details

Comment: In addition to the error regarding the Wild Die, this answer is incorrect in stating that it costs 1 benny per die when rerolling: "You can use Bennies to reroll any Trait test. _Make the entire roll from scratch._ If you’re firing three shots on full-auto and don’t like the results, pick up all three dice and your Wild Die and roll again." (Savage Worlds Deluxe, p. 63; emphasis mine)